# Implement Jquery UI sortable and resizable together

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-resizable

I"m trying to implement a sort and resize for a couple of divs in a grid-like layout.

This is an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmdGj/21/)

But the problem is once I resize(make the div bigger) and then when I try to sort the sort is not working properly. Instead of aligning properly it is overflowing out of the other div where the inner-divs are placed.

Resize is not working with the fiddle. This is the correct [result](http://jsfiddle.net/dmdGj/30/) that I need to achieve after resizing(assuming max-width resizable is the width of outer div). But in my code, if I try to resize, the elements are overlapping and again if I place it in the right side, the element is overflowing out of the outer container div. (In the [result](http://jsfiddle.net/dmdGj/30/)) it is not happening, try keeping div{3} at the position of div{2}

I'm using bootstrap fluid layout. so the divs are sized with span class. this is the code that I'm using

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="sortable">
            <div class="span6 sort_container"> <div class="well">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</div> </div>
            <div class="span6 sort_container"> <div class="well">bbbbbbbbbbbbb</div> </div>
            <div class="span6 sort_container" > <div class="well">ccccccccccc</div> </div>
            <div class="span6 sort_container"> <div class="well">dddddddddddd</div> </div>
            <div class="span6 sort_container"> <div class="well">eeeeeeeeeeee</div> </div>
        </div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    });

$(function() {
        $('.well').resizable();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `resizable` doesn't work in your JSfiddle

Comment: I rigged it to show the resize handle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dmdGj/38/)

Comment: @AbstractChaos seems the resize working pretty fine here in the jiddle now.. but not in my code. I addition: I'm using bootstrap fluid layout. so the divs are sized with span class.

Comment: do u have the css to go with that, specifically from your  jquery ui theme

Comment: Again works when css is added so I would say you are missing your css see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5QHAJ/)

Answer (score 5):

damn! I just figured out what went wrong. Instead of calling 'sort_container' class I called '.well' which is the inner div of the elements with resizable() function.

This solved it

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="sortable">
            <div class="span6 sort_container"> <div class="well">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</div> </div>
            <div class="span6 sort_container"> <div class="well">bbbbbbbbbbbbb</div> </div>
            <div class="span6 sort_container" > <div class="well">ccccccccccc</div> </div>
            <div class="span6 sort_container"> <div class="well">dddddddddddd</div> </div>
            <div class="span6 sort_container"> <div class="well">eeeeeeeeeeee</div> </div>
        </div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    });

$(function() {
        $('.sort_container').resizable();
    });
});
</script>
```

now only problem is the try increasing the height for about 150% of an element. It leaves some white space der. Is der any way to remove that and bring up the bottom element?

It aligns perfectly if resized horizontaly

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/5QHAJ/20/)

Answer (score -1):

$(function() {
        $(".column").sortable({
            connectWith : ".column",
            cursor : "move",
            handle : ".portlet-header",
            cancel : ".portlet-toggle",
            placeholder : "portlet-placeholder ui-corner-all",
            remove : function(event, ui) {
                console.log(event, ui);
            }
        });

```
    $(".portlet").addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all").find(".portlet-header").addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all").prepend(
            "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'></span>");

    $(".portlet-toggle").on("click", function() {
        var icon = $(this);
        icon.toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick");
        icon.closest(".portlet").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
    });

    $(".portlet").resizable();
});
```

try this code...........................................

https://jsfiddle.net/choisyong/xa7uhrd1/2/